# Use max-content in calc

Tags: css, calc

Imagine I have a `<div>` with some `<p>` in it:

```css
#myDiv {
  width: max-content;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
```

But I don't like the fact that the text is so close to the `border`, so I tried this:

```css
#myDiv {
  width: calc(max-content + 2px);
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
```

But (as you can see) it didn't work.

---

So my question is if there's a way to create a `<div>` with a width of

> *Two pixels more than the content in it*

since what I tried

```
calc(max-content + 2px)
```

didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `max-width` keyword with `calc()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unfortunately you can't use the `max-content` keyword with `calc()`

My solution to your problem would be to use padding:

```css
#myDiv {
  width: max-content;
  padding-inline: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason or documentation rule why `max-content` can't be used in `calc()`?

Comment: @JacobFord The [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-func) stipulates numerical values but doesn't really specify *why*. My guess is it would either be a pain or impossible to implement with how rendering engines work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `div` to behave like an `inline-block` element and add `padding: 2px` to it. I think it would work the same way as you want.
So, here's the code:

```css
#myDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
```